# Partial Send in Socket.BeginSend( List<ArraySegment> )?

Tags: .net, system.net.sockets

I have a question regarding the [System.Net.Socket.BeginSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38dxf7kt(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
public IAsyncResult BeginSend(
    IList<ArraySegment<byte>> buffers,
    SocketFlags socketFlags,
    AsyncCallback callback,
    object state
)
```

**If `SocketFlags.None` is indicated in `socketFlags` parameter, will all `buffers` be sent before `callback` is fired?**

- If the answer to the above question is **NO**: The `EndSend` method only returns the bytes of sent buffer. How to know which `ArraySegment`s are sent? I need stupidly loop down the buffers to find the sent ones? And will it possible that half `ArraySegment` is sent?
- If the answer to the above question is **YES**: Does it have any limit on the size for the `buffers`? What if I send 10MB `buffers` at once?

Generally I don't understand how the.NET processes the `ArraySegment` internally.  Will the `ArraySegment` buffers merged into a big buffer before sending?